# После использования VPN-расширения "CyberGhost" браузер перестал подключаться к некоторым сайтам

Tags: сеть, vpn, firefox-extension

Недавно я скачал расширение "CyberGhost", и после его использования заметил, что если VPN не включен - то я не могу заходить на некоторые сайты (вылезает окошко с надписью "попытка соединения не удалась"). Если же его включить - то всё работает.

В чём может быть проблема и что мне надо сделать, чтобы всё работало как раньше, без VPN?

Дополнение: также не работают некоторые сервисы uPlay (нельзя обновиться, нельзя скачать игру, не грузит из магазин и прочие разделы в клиенте)

[image: Проблема]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё решилось отключением брандмауэра Windows (OS Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

1. Полазать по настройкам расширения и может быть найти как оно правильно отключается.
2. Удалить расширение.
3. Создать ещё один профиль в браузере и поставить расширение туда.
4. Воспользоваться другим методом обхода блокировок.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на сайты не заходится при выключенном расширении. При включённом как раз всё работает

Comment: А если удалить расширение?

Comment: Уже решил. Проблема оказалась в брандмауэре Windows 7. Отключил его - всё заработало. Не знаю правда, повлиял ли на это VPN или нет, но главное, что вроде всё починилось.

Comment: О как неожиданно!